# AutoShardedBot discord.py использование автоматизации акаунта

Tags: python, discord

пишу дискорд бота хотел использовать автоматизацию акаунта (из акаунта сделать бота (для определенного сервера ))

```
import discord 
from discord.ext.commands import AutoShardedBot, when_mentioned_or 
 
client = AutoShardedBot(command_prefix="l!", case_insensitive=True) 
 
@client.event 
async def on_ready(): 
    print("Online.") 
 
 
 

 
client.run("токен")
```

ошибка
[image: ошибка]

Comment: Советую убрать токен. С помощью него можно получить доступ к аккаунту)

Comment: Ну я заранее убрал пару цифр, но вследущий раз буду писать словами токен. Спасибо за совет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас ошибка в импортах, вот как нужно сделать:

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="l!", case_insensitive=True)
```

`discord.ext.commands.AutoShardedBot` нужен только для тех ботов, который есть на 2000+ серверах, поэтому лучше просто используйте `discord.ext.commands.Bot` и всё.


Если Вы хотите сделать селф-бота, т.е. бота на пользователе, то **обратите внимание** на то, что Дискорд за такое может выдать перманентный бан!

Comment: Я знаю про бан (мне надо сделать для сервера на котором сидят друзья. Жалобу некто не кинет)